# Run nmap in a Docker container as a non-admin user

Tags: linux, security, docker, nmap

I'd like to run the Nmap tool in a Docker container but not with the default root user account. I already set the (hopefully) right capabilities via setcap.
Unfortunately, I get only the "operation not permitted" error when I try to run it.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.3

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

RUN microdnf install nmap which
RUN setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_net_bind_service+eip $(which nmap)

USER 1001

CMD ["nmap", "--privileged", "-sU", "localhost"]
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe SELinux issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is "cap_net_admin".

In order to use/set this capability inside a container, the container must be run with the "NET_ADMIN" capability.

```
# docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN <...>
```

Or simply omitting "cap_net_admin" from your setcap statement should work.

However, to run nmap the way you want, you many only need the "cap_net_raw" capability.

Reducing your dockerfile setcap command to:

```
RUN setcap cap_net_raw+eip $(which nmap)
```